# Memory Error thrown while trying to create dynamic arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, dynamic-arrays

For my assignment I need to make a dynamic array class which utilizes an addEntry and deleteEntry function. I've been looking for a while for this solution and can't find it. My code is as follows:

```
//headers
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Class Declaration
class DynamicStringArray {
    //private variables
private:
    //needs to be a pointer
    string *dynamicArray;
    int size;
public:
    //public functions
    DynamicStringArray();
    DynamicStringArray(const DynamicStringArray& array);
    int getSize();
    void addEntry(string entry);
    bool deleteEntry(string entry);
    string getEntry(int index);
    void operator= (const DynamicStringArray& equals);
    ~DynamicStringArray();
};

//default constructor
DynamicStringArray::DynamicStringArray() {
    dynamicArray = new string[0];
    size = 0;
}

//copy constructor
DynamicStringArray::DynamicStringArray(const DynamicStringArray& array) {
    //makes their size equal
    size = array.size;
    dynamicArray = new string[size];
    //copies the data over.
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        dynamicArray[i] = array.dynamicArray[i];
    }
}

//accessor method to get the size
int DynamicStringArray::getSize() {
    return size;
}

//adding an entry
void DynamicStringArray::addEntry(string entry) {
    string *tempArray = new string[size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tempArray[i] = dynamicArray[i];
    }
    //increment size
    size++;
    tempArray[size] = entry;
    //set dynamic array to the temp
    delete[] dynamicArray;
    dynamicArray = tempArray;
    //cleanup
    delete[] tempArray;
}

//delete entry
bool DynamicStringArray::deleteEntry(string entry) {
    bool found = false;
    bool replaced = false;
    int index;
    //checks for the value
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (dynamicArray[i] == entry) {
            found = true;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        return found;
    }
    //declaring temp array
    string *tempArray = new string[size - 1];
    //copies data over, skipping over the one not being coppied.
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (!replaced) {
            tempArray[i] = dynamicArray[i];
        }
        else if (replaced) {
            tempArray[i - 1] = dynamicArray[i];
        }
        if (i == index) {
            replaced = true;
        }
    }
    //setting dynamic array to the temp 
    delete[] dynamicArray;
    dynamicArray = tempArray;
    //de-increment
    size--;
    //cleanup
    delete[] tempArray;
    return true;
}

//accessor method to get the value at an index.
string DynamicStringArray::getEntry(int index) {
    return dynamicArray[index];
}

void DynamicStringArray::operator= (const DynamicStringArray& equals) {
    //makes their size equal
    size = equals.size;
    dynamicArray = new string[size];
    //copies the data over.
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        dynamicArray[i] = equals.dynamicArray[i];
    }
}

DynamicStringArray::~DynamicStringArray() {
    delete[] dynamicArray;
    dynamicArray = NULL;
}
int main()
{
    DynamicStringArray* test = new DynamicStringArray;
    cout << test->getSize() << endl;
    test->addEntry("joe");
    cout << test->getSize() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I commented out the addEntry and deleteEntry functions and it compiles fine. After I uncommented them out, I uncommented "test->addEntry("joe");" in the main method and it compiled fine.

The error thrown is:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Pnext was 0xFDFDFE01.
```

in the xmemory file, which I believe is just part of the visual studio library.

If there is any additional information you need please let me know.

Comment: You have one allocation (call to `new`) in `addEntry`, but two deletes.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm , Thanks for your response, just tried commenting out ```delete [] tempArray``` in ```addEntry``` just now and it still throws the same error.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica , The assignment specifies that the array has to be type string.

Comment: When you add the first string, what value does `size` have when you assign to `tempArray[size]`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm When the program reaches the first time I call ```cout << test->getSize() << endl;``` it outputs 0, the error gets thrown immediately after and I can't step through the debugger afterwards.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica I know that it's a much smarter solution to use a vector for this implementation, and the prompt states that it wants the class to act like a vector so I think that the professor wants us to use an array of strings, which I agree is extremely inefficient.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica How would I go about using the type ```char``` to implement this?

Comment: In `addEntry` you are incrementing `size` after your loop, then using that to index into `tempArray` which was allocated with length `size + 1`. That means you are indexing one past the end of the array.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica `s= new string[10]` and `delete[] s` are just fine.  The 10 strings allocated will be destroyed, then the memory freed.  (`delete s` - without the `[]` - would be Undefined Behavior.)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - thank you. I was unclear on how far the `delete[]` would try and free down the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with `addEntry`.  You have one allocation (call to `new`) with two deletes, which is fixed by removing the `delete [] tempArray;` from the end of the function (with it there, you delete the newly allocated memory leaving `dynamicArray` pointing to memory that is no longer allocated).

The other is that you increment `size` too soon.  You need to assign to `tempArray[size]` first, then increment size.

Comment: Fixing the ```size``` increment fixed that part of the program! Thank you!

Comment: oh sorry, I also deleted the extra delete calls.

Comment: That's after deleting the `detete[] tempArray;` call. If you have `valgrind` available, try it on your current code. Then add another entry (say `test->addEntry("blow");`). Check again. Things start spiraling out of control. Multiple `"Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()"` began appearing. Along with numerous `"Invalid read of size X"` errors.